# Passing data to Angular page from Node API

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

I want to be able to load a blog post when a user is directed to /feed/:id and I want this page to load in Angular.js. Basically I want Node to pass the post title, content, etc. to the Angular template in JSON format (post.html) and for Angular to use the JSON attributes of the post (post.name, post.content, etc...).

I know how to build the API on the Node side to get this data from a MongoDB datastore but I'm not entirely sure how to pass it on to the Angular controller once I have it in Node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass node.js server variables into my angular/html view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248394/how-do-i-pass-node-js-server-variables-into-my-angular-html-view)

Comment: there a numerous questions (and answers) about this. a simple search for "data nodejs angularjs" will help you, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834292/passing-data-to-angular-page-from-node-api