# How to save the selected button after refresh in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, session

//index.js where i start my session

```
  exports.index = function(req, res){

req.session.username = "sachin";
console.log(req.session.username);
if(req.session.username)
    {
console.log("Sessssion initialized");
    }
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

};
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
 });
```

//app.js

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

```
 var express = require('express')
 , routes = require('./routes')
 , user = require('./routes/user')
 , http = require('http')
 , path = require('path')
 , session = require('client-sessions');


 var app = express();
 app.use(session({   

 cookieName: 'session',    
 secret: 'cmpe273_test_string', 
  saveUninitialized: true, // (default: true)
    resave: true, 
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,    
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,  }));

 app.configure(function(){
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3070);
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.use(express.favicon());
 app.use(express.logger('dev'));
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes')));
 });

 app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  });

  app.get('/', routes.index);
```

//orders.ejs////////////

```
   <h3>Menu</h3>

   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead><tr>
  <th>Item Number</th>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr ng-repeat="item in items" >
  <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{ item.Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name={{$index}} ng-click="cal(item.id)"<br>       </td>
  </tr></tbody>
 </table>

  <button class="btn" ng-click="res()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Submit
  </button>
```

//order.js

```
/**
```

* New node file
 */

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   angular.module('myApp', []).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope)    {
    var json_responses
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.price = '';
    $scope.total=0;
    $scope.output=0;
    $scope.fina = [];
    $scope.finals=[];
    $scope.items = [
    {id:1, Name:'Garlic Bread',price:20 },
    {id:2, Name:'Butter Chicken',price:30 },
    {id:3, Name:'Tandoori Chicken',price:25 },
    {id:4, Name:'Naan',price:5},
    {id:5, Name:'Ice Cream',price:10},
    {id:6, Name:'Pizza',price:15 }
    ];
    $scope.cal=function(id){
         $scope.output = $scope.output+$scope.items[id-1].price;
         $scope.fina.push({id:$scope.items[id-1], Name:$scope.items[id-     1].Name,price:$scope.items[id-1].price}); 

    }


    $scope.res=function(fina){
        $scope.total= $scope.output;
        $scope.finals=angular.copy($scope.fina);
    }
  });
```

When i select the buttons and submit and get the bill and then refresh the page all the data is lost. How do i get the data to stay even after refreshing?? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You're using client-sessions to store state in the user's cookies but you're not actually storing the order details. You'll need to add another route to take the data and add it to the `req.session` object in the same way as you have with username. First you'll need to add the body-parser dependency by running `npm install body-parser --save`.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Use body-parser middleware to populate req.body from POST json data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/submit', function (req, res){
  //TODO check that the data is valid before just using it
  req.session.order = req.body.order;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

You need to modify the angular controller to post the data when calling `res()`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['$scope', '$http']).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  /* Existing code */
  $scope.res=function() {
    $scope.total= $scope.output;
    $scope.finals=angular.copy($scope.fina);
    $http.post('/submit', {order: $scope.finals});
  }
}
```

In general you're best using angular forms rather than doing it yourself with just a controller as they give you two-way data-binding but it can be instructive to learn it without the magic first.

Comment: This is the first time i am implementing sessions. So when you say get data from request exactly how do i get the data i.e. the selected values and output?

Comment: That depends how you send it. I'll update the answer to send JSON as a POST.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But when i edited the code as given above i got this error while debugging   Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error. Failed to instantiate module myApp. Any idea about that?

Comment: i changed the code to angular.module('myApp', [ ]).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $http) instead of angular.module('myApp', ['$scope', '$http']).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $http) and the error went . But now it says http://localhost:3070/submit not found.

Comment: The res.redirect('/'); command keeps send the control back to the same page with all the data refreshed. Not able to retain the data.

Comment: Oops, I used app.get instead of app.post, so it was saying that it couldn't find what to do with a POST to /submit

Comment: The module error you're seeing is most likely because you're calling `angular.module()` twice. The first time you call it for a module (in your case 'myApp') you need to define the dependencies, which is what the array argument is. It should work with just the line I've given and removing your call to `angular.module('myApp', [])`.

Comment: Also, I notice now that you're not actually displaying the order anywhere in the code above. You'll need to put something into your orders.ejs file to display the data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248394/how-do-i-pass-node-js-server-variables-into-my-angular-html-view for more details.